# Does javascript "await" pauses immediately whatever it is doing and resumes the async function once a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I just started learning async-await and just want to know the program execution flow clearly.

```
async function A() {
 await doSomethingAsync();
 doThisNext();
}

A();
B();
C();
```

Given that above code snippet, let's say B() is being executed at the moment.

1. While B() is executing and if doSomethingAsync() gets resolved right at that moment, will the programing execution suspends B() temporarily to resume A() (ie; start doThisNext() and then switch back?
2. Or will B() (or even C()) be finished up first and then executes doThisNext()?
3. Or I am misunderstanding the whole thing?

Assume B and C are just generic functions with no async code.

Comment: Resolution is always handled (at least) the next time the even loop executes. It will not make any sense otherwise, as the execution flow would have to jump around and likely even deadlock when multiple Promises are running.

Comment: You'll want to investigate the *single threaded nature* of Javascript and the *event loop*. In a nutshell, every function will always finish running and won't be interrupted in the middle. `await` is basically an explicit breakpoint at which a function *will* get interrupted to await the resolution of a promise. So, `A()` gets executed, gets suspended at `await`, then `B()` will run, then `C()`, then whenever the promise resolves, the execution of `A` will be resumed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> While B() is executing and if doSomethingAsync() gets resolved right at that moment, will the programing execution suspends B() temporarily to resume A() (ie; start doThisNext() and then switch back?

This is not how event loop works. If `B` is synchronous it wont be interrupted by promise resolution. Which is scheduled to be executed during current promise resolution micro-queue.

So, the order will be

1. A started and suspended
2. B ended
3. C ended
4. A resumed and ended

```js
A();
B();
C();



async function A() {
  console.log('A start');
  await delay(0);
  // or even
  // await Promise.resolve('done')
  console.log('A end')
}

function B() {
  console.log('B')
}

function C() {
  console.log('C')
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect it might be a helpful illustration too for OP to compare the behaviour of your sample to a version where we await A() before executing the others: https://jsfiddle.net/7kc68sj1/ . I think this helps to show that await suspends the current context and stops any further code executing in that context, until the promise resolves/rejects. So the difference is in my example, the whole of A() has to be executed (including waiting for the delay to complete) before B can run.

Comment: From what I gather (I am still digging), a non-async function execution can be thought of as an atomic execution unit where it can't be broken up?

And I also think A() can be resumed between B() and C(), but not while any of these are being executed.

Comment: @AungKhant It is more than that. Your function can still call another function and so one. In general current queue will be executed until there is something in call stack left. If you have say a broken recursion then engine wont be able to finish current loop and will eventually throw StackOverflow exception.

Comment: @ADyson I checked your fiddle. Thank you very much for that! I started to look among threads, because this question rose to me - might not be 100% related to the question, but still related to asynchronous programming: "okay, it seems `await` suspends execution. But does it suspend execution **globally**?". (Looking for an answer that would generalise). Judging by your fiddle and the accepted answer here, I came to this answer: "`await` suspends execution in the closest scope it resides". Is this correct? Because my assumption would satisfy both the accepted answer and your fiddle.